# How do I get the name right with alignment?

Tags: amsmath, alignment, amsthm

I have a code like  `\begin{aligned}{\emph{Culling}} \forall x(\Sigma(x)\leftrightarrow &   \Pi  \wedge\\ &   \forall m,n((m, y)\})\end{aligned}`, and amsmath & amsthm are among the packages.

The name appears in italic as *Culling* on the left hand side, and indented.

How may I get the name in standard font, flushed to the right in the first line? (Or, perhaps even better, flushed to the right in a line intermediate between the two lines in the body text.)

Update:

With reference to the suggestion by Anton Mn, here is an mwe which shows the insufficiency insufficiency with the proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\texttt{\alph*},align=left,ref=\texttt{\alph*}]
        \item $\forall y(\textnormal{Formula 1})$\null\hfill P 
    
    \item $\begin{aligned}{\emph{Name 0}}
        \forall x(\textnormal{Formula 2} &   \forall n(\textnormal{Formula 3}\\ &   \forall m,n(\textnormal{Formula 4})\end{aligned}$
    \item For $\alpha(y,z)$ a first order condition so that \ldots \null\hfill Name 1
    
    \item \[ 
    \begin{aligned}
        \forall x(\Sigma(x)\leftrightarrow &   \Pi  \wedge \\&   \forall m,n((m, y)\})
    \end{aligned}
    \tag{Name 2}
    \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
\[ 
 \begin{aligned}
   \forall x(\Sigma(x)\leftrightarrow &   \Pi  \wedge \\&   \forall m,n((m, y)\})
 \end{aligned}
 \tag{\emph{Culling}}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. In the enumeration environment, I have the indicator, g, appears leftmost, but half a line above your top line. So there is an ugly imbalance when I use your solution as an enumeration item.    Is there a simple way to resolve that?

Comment: @Sapiens: You can try: `\item $\begin{aligned}[t]\forall x(\textnormal{Formula 2} & \forall n(\textnormal{Formula 3}\\ &   \forall m,n(\textnormal{Formula 4})\end{aligned}$\hfill\emph{Name 0}`. I don't think it looks very good though. Neither do I find it esthetically pleasing if `Name 0` appeared in between the lines. But it's your call.

Comment: I agree with your aesthetical judgement, so I obtained a solution with g and Culling aligned with the top line; some of the information for that is in my Update.

Comment: The solution was based on the accepted for this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616643/how-do-i-get-the-left-numbering-central/616644#616644

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\begin{aligned} \forall x(\Sigma(x)\leftrightarrow &   \Pi  \wedge\\ &   \forall m,n((m, y)\})\end{aligned}\text{Constant}\label{eq:a}
\end{flalign}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\begin{aligned} \forall x(\Sigma(x)\leftrightarrow &   \Pi  \wedge\\ &   \forall m,n((m, y)\})\end{aligned} &\qquad &\text{(Constant)}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got: Package amsmath Error: \begin{flalign} allowed only in paragraph mode. \item$\begin{flalign}, when I tried your solution as an item in my enumeration environment. Why?

Comment: please show soure somehow

Comment: Can I place a mwe as an update to your question?

Comment: sorry I dont know what does mwe mean

Comment: Minimal working example, to show the source you ask for.

Comment: Yes as You wish

Comment: I updated my own question to provide more information.