# How do I get the left numbering central?

Tags: enumerate, line-numbering

Compiling the mwe below will illustrate why I would like the letter d on the left hand side to be on the same line as Name 2. How may I obtain that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\texttt{\alph*},align=left,ref=\texttt{\alph*}]
        \item $\forall y(\textnormal{Formula 1})$\null\hfill P 
     \item $\begin{aligned}{\emph{Name 0}}
        \forall x(\textnormal{Formula 2} &   \forall n(\textnormal{Formula 3}\\ &   \forall m,n(\textnormal{Formula 4})\end{aligned}$
    \item For $\alpha(y,z)$ a first order condition so that \ldots \null\hfill Name 1
    \item \[ 
    \begin{aligned}
        \forall x(\Sigma(x)\leftrightarrow &   \Pi  \wedge \\&   \forall m,n((m, y)\})
    \end{aligned}
    \tag{Name 2}
    \]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For item d, I used `$...$` instead of `\[...\]`, I changed the `\tag` to a simple `\hfill`, and I `[t]`op-aligned the `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\texttt{\alph*},align=left,ref=\texttt{\alph*}]
        \item $\forall y(\textnormal{Formula 1})$\null\hfill P 
     \item $\begin{aligned}{\emph{Name 0}}
        \forall x(\textnormal{Formula 2} &   \forall n(\textnormal{Formula 3}\\ &   \forall m,n(\textnormal{Formula 4})\end{aligned}$
    \item For $\alpha(y,z)$ a first order condition so that \ldots \null\hfill Name 1
    \item $ 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        \forall x(\Sigma(x)\leftrightarrow &   \Pi  \wedge \\&   \forall m,n((m, y)\})
    \end{aligned}
    $\hfill    Name 2

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want "d" and "Name 2" to be vertically central relative to the `aligned` expression, remove the `[t]` option from `aligned`.  In either case, "d" and `Name 2" will be vertically aligned.

[image]